# Where is Magento storing cross-reference data

Tags: magento, type-conversion, cross-reference

I am trying to convert a Magento shop to an oscommerce shop. The Magento shop sells print cartridges and has cross-referencing so a person can find which cartridge works with which printer. I was able to get the products copied but I don't know where the cross-reference data is stored. I'm not familiar with Magento, at least not to the point of being able to look at the code to figure out the tables used. I created a job in the Magento admin and exported the products but the csv file doesn't show any cross-reference data.

I have full access to the shop and its database - just don't know where to look. I don't know if the cross-reference code was added by a developer or if it is some plugin from Magento. I have versions 1 and 2 of Magento, in case that helps. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to figure out the cross-referencing?

Answer (score 2):

The feature is called cross-selling in Magento. In the Backend you find it while editing a product (Catalog => Manage Products) in the left menu, called "Cross-Selling".
Magento has 2 other types of such relations called "related-products" and "Up-Selling". Maybe you have to transfer that data too.
You can find these relations in the database in the table "catalog_product_link".

```
Link_type_id = 1 => relation
Link_type_id = 4 => up-selling
Link_type_id = 5 => cross-selling
```

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in responding. I did check the table mentioned but it is empty. But it turns out that the product export tool includes a list of the related products. It is not obvious when looking at it and I don't know if it is standard with Magento or just something this shop created but it allowed me to get what I needed. Thank you for trying to help. I have up-counted your reply.